# From a conditional expectation to expectation containing an indicator function

Tags: probability, expected-value

Could someone explain how we get from the condition on the left hand-side to the term on the right hand-side which contains the indicator functions.
I am especially interested in what probability laws I need to use and understanding the steps.

$$E[\mathit{Y} \vert \mathit{A=a}] = \frac{E[\mathit{Y} \mathit{I}(\mathit{A=a})]}{E[\mathit{I}(\mathit{A=a})]} $$

The $\mathit{I}(\mathit{A=a})$ function is an indicator function that equals 1 when $\mathit{A=a}$ and 0 otherwise. In addition, $\mathit{Y}$ and $\mathit{A}$ are discrete random variables.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\mathbb{E}[Y|A =a] = \sum_y y \mathbb{P}(Y=y|A=a) = \sum_y y \frac{\mathbb{P}(Y = y, A = a)}{\mathbb{P}(A=a)}$

$\mathbb{P}(A=a) = \mathbb{E}[1_{A = a}]$ as can be seen quite easily. So let's focus on the numerators.

$\sum_y y\mathbb{P}(Y = y, A = a)= \sum_y y \cdot 1 \mathbb{P}(Y = y, 1_{A = a} = 1) + \sum_{y}y \cdot 0 \mathbb{P}(Y = y, 1_{A = a} = 0) = \mathbb{E}[Y1_{A=a}]$.

Thus putting it all together gives us $\mathbb{E}[Y|A=a] = \frac{\mathbb{E}[Y1_{A=a}]}{\mathbb{E}[1_{A=a}]}$

Answer (score 0):

$E[Y|E]=\frac {E[YI_E]} {P(E)}$. This the definition of $E[Y|E]$. Take $E$ to be event $I(A=a)$. Now the only thing you need is the equation $E[I(A=a)]=P(A=a)$.